# General function to color applicable comboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running some VBA code in Excel and I made a a combo box that will turn red and set the focus on it when there is no value entered.

```
 If cmb = "" Then
    cmb.BackColor = vbRed
    lbl.ForeColor = vbRed
    cmb.SetFocus
    Exit Sub

    Else

    cmb.BackColor = vbWhite
   lbl.ForeColor = vbBlack
End If
```

As I have many combo boxes on my form, I want to build a function or procedure that I can call for any combo box that I want.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general function that you can pass a `ComboBox` to:

```
Function ValidateComboBox(c As ComboBox) As Boolean

    If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then
        c.BackColor = vbRed
        Controls(c.Tag).ForeColor = vbRed    ' Set associated label color, also
        c.SetFocus
        ValidateComboBox = False
    Else
        c.BackColor = vbWhite
        Controls(c.Tag).ForeColor = vbBlack  ' Set associated label color, also
        ValidateComboBox = True
    End If

End Function
```

You call it like this, for example when the form is submitted:

```
' [OK] clicked. Submit form...
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    If Not ValidateComboBox(ComboBox1) Then Exit Sub
    If Not ValidateComboBox(ComboBox2) Then Exit Sub
    If Not ValidateComboBox(ComboBox3) Then Exit Sub
    ...

End Sub
```

The tricky part is that you have a label that corresponds to each combo box that needs to be updated as well. You can either design the function to accept both a `ComboBox` control and a `Label` control and pass both each time, or you take advantage of the combo box's `Tag` property, as I've done above. For each combo box, just enter the name of the corresponding `Label` control into its `Tag` property using the `Properties` window in the designer.

For example, if `ComboBox1` has a label named `Label1`, then enter `"Label1"` (without the quotes) into `ComboBox1`'s `Tag` property. The routine above will look for the label/control with that name and set its color appropriately as well.

Comment: HI Bud, it worked like a charm, Only thing I dunno why it not when I'm trying to leverage it to the TextBox a so:

Function ValidateTextBox(T As TextBox) As Boolean

  '  If Len(T.Text) = 0 Then
        T.BackColor = vbRed
        Controls(T.Tag).ForeColor = vbRed    ' Set associated label color, also
        T.SetFocus
        ValidateTextBox = False
    Else
        T.BackColor = vbWhite
        Controls(T.Tag).ForeColor = vbBlack  ' Set associated label color, also
        ValidateTextBox = True
    End If

Comment: @Hamdi - It doesn't work with the TextBox? Are you getting an error? Feel free to post a new question and add your code and I can take a look.

Comment: /* Function ValidateTextBox(T As TextBox) As Boolean

    If Len(T.Text) = 0 Then
        T.BackColor = vbRed
        Controls(T.Tag).ForeColor = vbRed    ' Set associated label color, also
        T.SetFocus
        ValidateTextBox = False
    Else
        T.BackColor = vbWhite
        Controls(T.Tag).ForeColor = vbBlack  ' Set associated label color, also
        ValidateTextBox = True
    End If

End Function */

Comment: @ Bond
It highlights the function with a type mismatch error

Comment: Replace `Function ValidateTextBox(T As TextBox) As Boolean` with `Function ValidateTextBox(T As MsForms.TextBox) As Boolean`